# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus with variable limits and multiple dimensions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to apply the Fundamental theorem of calculus in two dimensions with one of the limits shared by both integrals. Specifically, the problem I am trying to solve is: If $$F(x)=\int_a^x\int_x^b f(y,z)\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z, $$ then calculate $F'(x)$. I tried by using the definition of a derivative and breaking the integral into two pieces:

\begin{aligned}
\frac{F(x+\Delta)-F(x)}{\Delta} &= \frac{1}{\Delta}\left[\int_a^x \int_{x+\Delta}^bf(y,z)\mathrm{d}y-\int_x^bf(y,z)\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z +\int_{x}^{x+\Delta}\int_{x+\Delta}^bf(y,z)\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z \right] \\ 
&= \frac{1}{\Delta}\left[-\int_a^x \int_x^{x+\Delta}f(y,z)\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z +\int_{x}^{x+\Delta}\int_{x+\Delta}^bf(y,z)\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z \right]
\end{aligned}
Now, for the first term, I can apply l'Hôpital with respect to $\Delta$ but for the second term, I got stuck. Any ideas on how to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the Leibniz formula for differentiating $\int_a^x g(x,z)dz$.

Comment: As general advice for handling problems like this with the same variable occurring in different locations: Define $G(u,v) = \int_z^u \int_v^b f(y,z)dydz$ and $H(x) = (x,x)$. Then you have $F(x) = G\circ H(x)$ and can apply the multivariate chain-rule.